# Parse exception in Java

Tags: java, date

I am getting parse exception while running the below code, Is there anything wrong in the format ?

```
try {
    String Resolved= "17-04-2015 03:54" ;
    Date date  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z").parse(Resolved);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I dont see seconds and a timezone specifier?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your format string is: `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z"`.

`z` represents the timezone. You don't have a timezone in the string you try to parse: `"17-04-2015 03:54"`. (And you don't have seconds).

Change your format string to: `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"` and you should be fine!

Answer (score 1):

For your case, change

```
Date date  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z").parse(Resolved);
```

to

```
Date date  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").parse(Resolved);
```